# how to reduce the total number of scan in a mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I want to display some limited records from the following query but how should i reduced the total number of scan s that perform in the query using joins and make execution faster?

Query::

```
select ml.*,m.title as medianame,mt.name as media_type,d.device_name as devicename,
SUBTIME(ml.end_time,ml.start_time) as playback_duration,d.client_id
from device_media_log ml left join media m on m.media_id = ml.media_id left join device d on d.device_id = ml.device_id
left join media_type mt on m.media_type_id = mt.media_type_id
order by ml.play_date desc,ml.start_time desc,ml.end_time desc;
```

All tables contain required indexes.

Comment: Do you really need to get ALL data from four tables? Any conditions, paging!?

Comment: no i need all data from only device_media_log table according to the joins.

Comment: How paging should be used here n what differrence it should make?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing that I would recommend is to use where clauses where possible.

select ml.*,m.title as medianame,mt.name as media_type,d.device_name as devicename, SUBTIME(ml.end_time,ml.start_time) as playback_duration,d.client_id from device_media_log ml left join media m on m.media_id = ml.media_id left join device d on d.device_id = ml.device_id left join media_type mt on m.media_type_id = mt.media_type_id WHERE SOMETHING=SOMETHING AND SOMETHING=SOMETHING order by ml.play_date desc,ml.start_time desc,ml.end_time desc;

Comment: where clause is there still it had some problems. Mmeory exausted error found while fetching data.

Comment: did you run EXPLAIN with this query to see what is taking more time. When you say memory exhausted, I assume that you might be getting a big result set.

Comment: yes i explained this one. all table fetching single row but device_media_log fetches around 3million rows. how should i reduced that??

Comment: What part query execution is taking more time. "Copying to tmp table" or "Sorting result"

Comment: '1', 'SIMPLE', 'ml', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2944805', 'Using filesort'
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'm', 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '8', 'x.ml.media_id', '1', ''
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'd', 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '8', 'x.ml.device_id', '1', ''
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'mt', 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '8', 'x.m.media_type_id', '1', ''

Comment: Please run profiler for your query as mentioned [Here](http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2011/04/18/mysql-servers-built-in-profiling-support/)

Comment: I run the profile. the query takes lots of its time in sorting and sending the data.

Comment: 'Sorting result', '19.895972'
'Sending data', '33.045781'